# What's this castle all about?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I just joined a game of TF2 to find myself on some sort of castle map, with no guns allowed.  What are the rules here, and what weapons are usable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you've stumbled across the [Medieval Mode](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medieval_Mode) map [Degroot Keep](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Degroot_Keep).

> Medieval Mode is a game mode added to TF2 during the Australian Christmas event with the December 17, 2010 update.

The game play is different with only non-ranged weapons (apart from bows or crossbows) allowed, amongst other changes including "Ye Olde English" for chat, for example:

> "it was" gets replaced by "'twas"

Answer (score 3):

It's [Medieval mode](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Medieval_Mode), and no ranged weapons are allowed except for bows and crossbows. See the link for the full list.